# Organizing the files under the group name

Tags: r, dplyr

The data I have look like in a list:

G085_1.csv, G085_2.csv, G085_3.csv, .. G100_1.csv, G100_2.csv, .. G173_1, csv., G173_2, csv., G173_3.csv

where G stands for the group followed by the identification of each group member (1, 2, or 3). Notably, some groups do not have all three members.

What I'm trying to do is to create a loop for running the following code (an example for 1 group) for the entire groups.

```
i1 <- fread("sample/G085_1.csv")
i2 <- fread("sample/G085_2.csv")
i3 <- fread("sample/G085_3.csv")
```

What I have been doing is:

```
Groups <- c()
for(g in 85:173){
  Groups[g] <- ifelse(g<100,
                      paste0("G0", g),
                      paste0("G", g))
}

Members <- c("i1", "i2", "i3")
for(g in 1:length(Groups)){
  for(m in 1:3) {
    filename<- paste0("i",m)
    wd <- paste0("sample/", Groups[g],"_",
                 m, ".csv")
    ifelse(file.exists(wd),assign(filename,fread(wd)),
           function(){})
  }
   assign(Groups[g],...
         )
}
```

The place that I'm stuck in is the last part (**assign(Groups[g]...**). I'm not sure what would allow for calling in all the i1, i2, i3 dataframes for each group under the group. Is there a better way than using assign function here?

Comment: So for each group (`G085`, `G086` etc) you want to `assign` `i1`, `i2`, `i3` (whichever is present). What do you want to do after that? By the way, instead of using `assign` you should store the data in a list.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not exactly assign to `i1`, `i2`, `i3` but will gave you a list for your work with the Group names assgined to the list items. Each group item is a list contain three `data.frame` read from the files. In case the file not exists the item will be NULL.

#### Using foreach approach

```
library(foreach)
list_data <- foreach(g = Groups, .final = function(x) { setNames(x, Groups) }) %do% {
  current_group <- foreach(m = 1:3) %do% {
    filename<- paste0("i",m)
    wd <- paste0("sample/", Groups[g],"_",
      m, ".csv")
    data <- ifelse(file.exists(wd) , fread(wd), NULL)
    
    return(data)
  }
  
  return(current_group)
}
```

#### Using `purrr` map

```
library(purrr)

item_index <- c(1:3)
all_group_data <- map(.x = Groups, .f = function(g) {
  list_files <- paste0("sample/", g,"_", item_index, ".csv")
  group_data <- map(.x = list_files, .f =  function(file) {
    if (file.exists(file)) {
      data <- fread(file)
    } else {
      data <- NULL
    }
    data
  })
  group_data
})

names(all_group_data) <- Groups
```

Comment: Thank you @Sinh Nguyen I really like your foreach code! But I'm keep on getting an error message that "replacement has length zero" and "In rep(no, length.out = len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL"... Does this have to do with the place of the brackets for looping?